# Why does my fur grow on the other side?

Tags: hair

I'm not sure why my fur doesn't follow the surface normal.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your project, but I assume that the problem is related to the position of the instanced mesh relative to it's own origin. If the original "fur piece" mesh is below it's own origin (or if it's "upside down" without rotation applied), the particles will appear "below" the surface of the emitter mesh. If this is the case, select the "fur piece", enter edit mode, select all and move it "up" on the z-axis, keeping an eye on what it does to the position of the instanced particles.